# Проверка строки на длину, наличие заглавной литеры и цифры. Проверка пароля в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, пароль

Всем привет,
Хочу решить задачу на Javascript без использования массива и метода find():
У пользователя запрашивается пароль, при этом длина пароля от 4-х до 30-и символов, минимум 1 прописную (большую) букву и минимум 1 цифру.

Я вижу решение данной задачи примерно так:

```
let pass = prompt('Введите пароль');
pass = pass.trim();
if (length.pass < 4 || length.pass > 30 || pass == pass.toLowerCase() || pass != pass.indexOf(/\d/)){
alert('Пароль не удовлетворяет условиям! Перезагрузите страницу и попробуйте ввести его еще раз.');
} else if (pass == pass.lastIndexOf(/\d/)){
alert('Пароль валидный. Добро пожаловать в аккаунт!');
} else {
alert(`Ошибка`);
}
```

Однако, думаю, что у меня есть ошибка в проверке наличия цифры в пароле, хотя использовала проверку и indexOf с lastIndexOf.
Кто-нибудь решал аналогичную задачу?

Comment: Есть же уже [куча готовых решений](https://npm.io/search/keyword:password+strength)?!

Comment: вы пытаетесь сравнить строку `pass` с целым числом `pass.lastIndexOf(/\d/)`. Так не надо делать. Используйте IDE и строгое сравнение === с проверкой типов. Видимо, мы хотели использовать что-то типа `pass.match(/\d/)?.index >= 0 && pass.match(/\w/)?.index >= 0` (выражение проверяет, есть ли в пароле как цифра, так и буква. Наличие заглавной буквы можно проверить и через сравнение с `toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 3):

Такие вещи проверяются функциями валидаторами, которые будут проверять строку на соответствие нужным вам условиям.

Для каждого условия своя функция с проверкой. Эта же функция может выбросить соответствующую ошибку. Например вариант попроще:

```js
function lengthLessThan(str, limit) {
 return str.length < limit;
}

function lengthMoreThan(str, limit) {
  return str.length > limit;
}

function hasCapitalLetters(str) {
  return /[A-ZА-Я]/.test(str);
}

function hasDigits(str) {
  return /[0-9]/.test(str);
}

function isPasswordValid(str) {
  if (lengthLessThan(str, 4)) { // проверяем на длину строки
    console.error('Пароль должен быть длиннее 4 символов');
    return false; // если < 4 возвращаем false
  }
  if (lengthMoreThan(str, 30)) { // проверяем на длину строки
    console.error('Пароль должен быть короче 30 символов');
    return false; //  если > 30 возвращаем false
  }
  if (!hasCapitalLetters(str)) { // проверяем строку на соответсвие с регулярным выражением, которое ищет заглавные буквы в строке 
    console.error('Пароль должен содержать хотя бы одну заглавную букву');
    return false; // если заглавных букв нет, возвращаем false 
  }
  if (!hasDigits(str)) { // проверяем строку на соответсвие с регулярным выражением, которое ищет цифры в строке 
    console.error('Пароль должен содержать хотя бы одну цифру');
    return false; // если цифр нет, возвращаем false 
  }
  return true; // если все условия соблюдены, то функция вернет true - строка str валидна
}

console.log(
  isPasswordValid('absd1A'), // true
  isPasswordValid('abs'), // false
  isPasswordValid('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'), //false
  isPasswordValid('qew1'), // false
  isPasswordValid('qewA'), // false
);
```

Такой подход хоть и понятный, но не самый лучший, т.к плохо переиспользуемый из-за захардкоженых значений в функциях. Он вполне может устроить новичка, т.к выполняет свою задачу на данный момент. Но, что если появится другая форма для ввода пароля и этот пароль должен будет соответствать уже другим требованиям? Можно конечно скопировать уже сужествующую функцию, переименовать и дополнить/изменить, но тогда получим повторение кода.

Чтобы этого избежать можно применить другой подход, где мы имеем функцию, которая будет принимать строку для валидации и массив с функциями валидаторами. Пробегая по массиву в цикле, мы можем понять на каком моменте не прошла валидация, или еcли весь цикл был пройден без ошибок, то строка будет валидной.

Реализация может быть примерно такой:

```js
/**
* Ошибки для каждого валидатора
*/
const errors = {
  minLength: (limiter) => new Error(`Пароль должен быть больше ${limiter} символов`),
  maxLength: (limiter) => new Error(`Пароль должен быть меньше ${limiter} символов`),
  pattern: () => new Error(`Пароль должен содержать хотя бы одну заглавную букву и одну цифру`),
};

/**
 * @typedef {Object} ValidatorsResponse
 */

/**
* Объект Validators, выступающий в качестве пространства имен для функций валидаторов, так будет сразу понятно, для чего и откуда эти функции в коде
* @namespace Validators
*/
const Validators = {};
/**
* @memberof Validators
* @param {number} limit - минимально допустимое кол-во символов
* @returns {minLength~inner} - вернет функцию
*/
Validators.minLength = function(limit) {
  /**
  * @param {string} str
  * @returns {(ValidatorsResponse | Error)}
  * Проверяет длинну строки. Если длина < limit возвращает Error
  */
  return function minLength(str) {
    return str.length >= limit ? { [this.name]: { value: str, limit }} 
                               : errors[this.name](limit);
  }
}
/**
* @memberof Validators
* @param {number} limit - максимальное допустимое кол-во символов
* @returns {maxLength~inner} - вернет функцию
*/
Validators.maxLength = function(limit) {
  /**
  * @param {string} str
  * @returns {(ValidatorsResponse | Error)}
  * Проверяет длинну строки. Если длина > limit возвращает Error
  */
  return function maxLength(str) {
    return str.length <= limit ? { [this.name]: { value: str, limit }} 
                               : errors[this.name](limit);
  }
}
/**
* @memberof Validators
* @param {RegExp} regexp - регулярное выражение
* @returns {pattern~inner} - вернет функцию
*/
Validators.pattern = function(regexp) {
  /**
  * @param {string} str
  * @returns {(ValidatorsResponse | Error)}
  * Проверяет на соответствия между регулярным выражением regexp и строкой str.
  */
  return function pattern(str) {
    const valid = regexp.test(str); // проверяем строку с помощью регулярного выражения
    return valid ? { [this.name]: { value: str }} 
                 : errors[this.name]();
  };
}

/**
* @function isPasswordValid
* @param {string} str - строка для проверки
* @params {Array} validators - массив с функциями валидаторов
* @returns {boolean} Вернет соответствующее булево значение в зависимости от валидности строки str 
*/
function isPasswordValid(str, validators) {
  try {
    for (let validate of validators) {
      const validated = validate.call(validate, str);
      if (validated instanceof Error) throw validated; // если валидатор вернул ошибку, выкидываем ошибку дальше, чтобы обработать ее в блоке catch
    }
    return true; // если все хорошо, возвращаем true, строка прошла валидацию
  } catch (err) { // обрабатываем ошибку
    console.error(err.message); // выводим сообщение ошибки в консоль или в alert
    return false; // возвращаем false, строка не прошла валидацию
  }
};

/**
* Набор валидаторов для данного случая
*/
const validators = [
  Validators.minLength(4), // length > 4
  Validators.maxLength(30), // length < 30
  Validators.pattern(/[A-ZА-Я]/), // есть заглавные буквы
  Validators.pattern(/[0-9]/) // есть цифры
  /**
  * и так можно сюда сколько угодно таких функций валидаторов добавить
  */
];

console.log(
  isPasswordValid('absd1A', validators), // true
  isPasswordValid('abs', validators), // false
  isPasswordValid('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', validators), //false
  isPasswordValid('qew1', validators), // false
  isPasswordValid('qewA', validators), // false
);
```

Не идеально, но я только хотел передать саму суть подхода.

Добавил аннотации `JSDoc` и комментарии почти для каждого шага, чтобы было понятно, что и для чего.

В обоих случаях `console.error` можно заменить на `alert` - это не принципиально. И все будет работать.

Справочный материал, который может понадобится для понимания:

- [Введение в JSDoc](https://coderlessons.com/articles/veb-razrabotka-articles/vvedenie-v-jsdoc)
- [Методы объекта, "this"](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods#klyuchevoe-slovo-this-v-metodah)
- [Явное указание this: "call", "apply"](https://learn.javascript.ru/call-apply)
- [Тернарный опреатор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
- [Перехват ошибок try...catch](https://learn.javascript.ru/exception)

Answer (score 0):

Вам придется усложнить проверку. 
Вам передается строка и все цифры в строке это строки...
Придется преобразовывать каждый символ из строки и проверять значение

```js
const pass = ['dfg', 'fhgkeydn', 'dfkjGkj8l', 
'*sdkgfjkKjl8', 'jjsfljslfjsldfjlsfjlsdfjlfjsdflsdjflsdldjflsf;a', 
'&slfjl9jkjJ', '12345678901234567890123445678901234567890', 
'1234567890123456789O123456', '1234567890123456789@123456'];

/** @param {string} input */
function checkPass(input) {
  if (input.length < 4) return false;
  if (input.length > 30) return false;
  let up = false;
  let num = false;
  const reg = /[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]/g;
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    /** @type {string} */
    const check = input[i];
    if (isNaN(parseInt(check))) { // string
      if (reg.test(check)) {
        if (check === check.toUpperCase()) up = true
      }
    } else { // число
      num = true;
    }
    if (up && num) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

pass.forEach((item, index) => {
  console.log(index, checkPass(item))
})
```

Если решение подходит, вставляем функцию в ваш код

```
let pass = prompt('Введите пароль');
pass = pass.trim();
if (!checkPass(pass)){
    alert('Пароль не удовлетворяет условиям! Перезагрузите страницу и попробуйте ввести его еще раз.');
} else {
    alert('Пароль валидный. Добро пожаловать в аккаунт!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```js
function checkPasswordStrength(pwd) {
  return /.{4,30}/.test(pwd) * (
    + /[a-zа-яё]/.test(pwd)
    + /[A-ZА-ЯЁ]/.test(pwd)
    + /\d/.test(pwd)
    + /[^A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яЁё]/.test(pwd)
   );
}

['change', 'keyup', 'input'].forEach(function(eventName) {
    document.getElementById("pwd")
        .addEventListener(eventName, function() { 
           document.getElementById("strength").value =
               checkPasswordStrength(this.value);
         });
    });
```

```html
<label for="pwd">Password:</label>
<p><input type="password" id="pwd" /></p>
<p><progress id="strength" value="0" max="4"></progress></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```js
var password = document.querySelector(".password");
password.innerHTML = `
    <label for="passCheckOne">введите пароль</label>
        </br>
        <input type="password" id="passCheckOne" minlength="8" oninput="checkPass(); passSpec()" title="">
        </br>
    <label for="passCheckTwo">повторите пароль</label>
        </br>
        <input type="password" id="passCheckTwo" minlength="4" maxlength="30" oninput="checkPass()" disabled>
        </br>
        </br>
        <input type="submit" onsubmit="submitPass()">
`;

function passSpec() {
    var passFirth = document.querySelector("#passCheckOne");
    var title = document.querySelector("#passCheckOne").title;

    if (!/[A-Z]/.test(passFirth.value) || 
        !/[0-9]/.test(passFirth.value) || 
        !/[a-z]/.test(passFirth.value) || 
        passFirth.value.length < 4     || 
        passFirth.value.length > 30) {
        title = "пароль должен содержать минимум 4 и максимум 30 символов а также: A-Z , a-z, 0-9";
        var inputDisable = document.querySelector("#passCheckTwo");
        inputDisable.disabled = true;

    } else {
        title = "";
        var inputDisable = document.querySelector("#passCheckTwo");
        inputDisable.disabled = false;
    }
    passFirth.title = title;
}
```

```html
<div class="password"></div>
   
    <script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]